# Subsite vanished

Tags: 2013, restore

We have very puzzling issue with customer's SharePoint 2013 environment.

On Monday an admin user accidentally deleted the root site collection of the Intranet (cleaned out unused workspaces through Central Admin). We were able to restore the site collection with PowerShell using Get-SPDeletedSite and Restore-SPDeletedSite cmdlets.
After the restore we found out that some SharePoint forms were not found and found out that the subsite hosting those forms is nowhere to be found. Those forms were used to request changes for workspaces and list entries were forwarded to request management through SharePoint workflow.

Of course we have backups running so we took backup of the content database from Sunday, but no subsite to be found in restore to alternative web application. Then we went back a month old backup but still no subsite to be found. It is profoundly puzzling as we have ULS logs and IIS logs that there has been activity on that subsite as well as the requests in ticketing system on changes to the workspaces.

I went ahead down to read the content database and verified that AllWebs database table does not list the subsite in question. (I know you are not supposed to touch SP DBs but reading should not hurt anything :)

Tried locating orphaned webs by running "stsadm -o enumallwebs > d:\temp\subwebs.xml  2>&1" as is suggested in http://wendy-neal.com/2011/12/orphaned-site-issue-when-attempting-to-backuprestore-a-sharepoint-site-collection/ but this lists the same data which I can see from SQL directly.

So it seems that that subsite has not existed though it has been used actively.

Has anyone encountered such situation where a subsite has existed but cannot be found later on?